# MySQL slow connection

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, performance, database-performance

I am running a laravel application that is on a separate server than my MySQL database.

If I run the query on the Mysql server it takes the expected 0.00 - 0.01 seconds to return. However when I log the time from the start of a query to the end it takes .3secs. The whole API call takes between 800-1000ms.

I have changed my.cnf to skip-name-resolve, I have query cache turned on, I am using the IP and not the domain name for the connection.

I am not sure what else to try. This is a very simple RestAPI with simple queries and nothing complicated, and the largest table in the database has 9000 rows. I don't think it's a database issue, but a connection issue.

The CPU is only ever using 1%, and there is plenty of memory.

Any tricks I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried running SAME QUERY from laravel host using MYSQL CLIENT? Any change in performance ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the slow performance was from my servers being in different regions / data centers.

After doing a traceroute  it was taking average 40sec, and with 3ish queries per transaction that was adding up.

I create a new server in the same region and it is now much faster with a typical response being between 150-200ms.